# Do I need complex endorsement in each class or type of aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, logbook-endorsements

I have experiences with PA28R and got a complex endorsement from my instructor.
Now, I am working on multi add-on and flying DA42 Twinstar.

Do I need another complex endorsement that specifies the class and the type of the  aircraft for DA42 checkride?

Answer (score 4):

You only need one complex endorsement under FAA regulations,

> **[§61.31   Type rating requirements, additional training, and
>   authorization requirements.](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_131)**
>
> (c) Aircraft category, class, and type ratings: Limitations on the
>   carriage of persons, or operating for compensation or hire. Unless a
>   person holds a category, class, and type rating (**if a class and type
>   rating is required**) that applies to the aircraft, that person may not
>   act as pilot in command of an aircraft that is carrying another
>   person, or is operated for compensation or hire. That person also may
>   not act as pilot in command of that aircraft for compensation or hire.
>
> (e) Additional training required for operating complex airplanes. (1)
>   Except as provided in paragraph (e)(2) of this section, no person may
>   act as pilot in command of a complex airplane, unless the person has—
>
> (i) Received and logged ground and flight training from an authorized
>   instructor in a complex airplane, or in a flight simulator or flight
>   training device that is representative of a complex airplane, and has
>   been found proficient in the operation and systems of the airplane;
>   and
>
> (ii) Received a **one-time endorsement** in the pilot's logbook from an
>   authorized instructor who certifies the person is proficient to
>   operate a complex airplane.

In your case a class rating is only required for the "multi" aspect of the DA-42 as the DA-42 has no type rating.

The FAA further more defines complex aircraft as

> *[Complex airplane](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=257acc4699ee7253af775fc7e9492e51&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_11)* means an airplane that has a retractable landing
>   gear, flaps, **and a controllable pitch propeller**, including airplanes
>   equipped with an engine control system consisting of a digital
>   computer and associated accessories for controlling the engine and
>   propeller, such as a full authority digital engine control; or, in the
>   case of a seaplane, flaps and a controllable pitch propeller,
>   including seaplanes equipped with an engine control system consisting
>   of a digital computer and associated accessories for controlling the
>   engine and propeller, such as a full authority digital engine control.

No part of this definition stipulates how many engines the aircraft has.